# Gremlin: Select Vertices that have edges that share a property

Tags: scala, graph, gremlin

This is in gremlin-scala. I have the traversal at a Vertex point (which is what '_' stands for below:

```
 _.as("vertex").outE().as("outEdge").in().inE().as("inEdge")
.select("inEdge","outEdge").by("fullName")
.where("inEdge", P.eq("outEdge")).select("vertex")
```

But I am getting an error referencing the .in() after the .as("outEdge") statement:

```
Error:(55, 40) Cannot prove that org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Edge <:< gremlin.scala.Vertex.
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going wrong here, and more importantly, ***is this the correct way to find Vertices*** that have a matching property on its edges?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that syntax is incorrect. Change:

```
_.as("vertex").outE().as("outEdge").in()
```

to

```
_.as("vertex").outE().as("outEdge").inV()
```

when you do `outE()` you are on an edge, so you must traverse to a Vertex which would be either `inV()` (the vertex adjacent to where you started), `outV()` (the vertex you started from since you traversed `outE()`, or `bothV()` which would yield both the vertices at either end of the edge.

I think your method for comparing properties makes sense. Someone else might post a way to simplify further.